# Apple Wallet Authentication Token with special word

Tags: web-services, wallet

This question is related to pass update.

Since the .pkpass file send out to customers, we never know they open the pass in which method. For getting the return header of authorization, I use the keywords '**ApplePass** ' as begin, after the testing in a short time, some of them may using '**AttidoPass** ' or '**AndroidPass** ' to return the authorization token.　**However, it is hard to find out user how to install the .pkpass .**

In today case, a 'boarding pass' try to update pass, but there is no any header value when it call the web service.

**Anybody know what method for that user update pass?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AttidoPass and AndroidPass are custom user agents of Android applications that mimic Apple Wallet.  Each service has it's own API and protocol for updates and you will need to contact the app developer for instructions and credentials.

For Attido, the developer documentation can be found [here](http://passwallet.attidomobile.com/PassWallet%20Developer%20Guide.pdf).